# how to sort 5 strings according to their length and print it out

Tags: c++, string

I am basically a super newbie to c++  so we were asked in class today to write a basic program that will print 5 names like this:
String1
String11
String111
String1111
String11111
But the names will be arranged in descending order
Thanks In advance I will be grateful and if there is a place were this has already been address place direct me towards it cos I have searched and couldn't find what would have helped me.

Comment: Look at `std::sort`...

Comment: Show us what you've done so far to try to solve this problem with a [mcve].

Comment: I don't know how to use std::sort maybe u could show me a basic syntax?

Comment: create `std::string s{"String"};`, `std::vector<std::string> v;` and then use a `for` loop to do `s += "1"; v.push_back(s)`. Then reverse with `std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());`

Comment: I've not written any code looking at it confuses me some more. Am coming from Python.

Comment: Really?  You can't find the syntax of [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?  I recommend searching the internet for "C++ sort syntax" and see what comes up.

Comment: You guys didn't understand that am a newbie at this. wouldn't even attempt c++ its an  assignment from school coming from python its pretty strange learning c++. @AlBundy i just want to finish my assignment in time.  thanks

Comment: Only excuses. Yes, there is no time to use punctuation and so on... Instead of writing the **useless excuse** you could reformat your question! With this attitude you are going to fail!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested you can use sort

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  std::vector<string> vec={"abc","defsf","a","c"}; 
  cout<<"Unsorted string"<<endl;
  for(auto s: vec)
  {
      cout<<s<<" ";
  }
  std::sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),[](const string& a,const string& b)
    {
        return a.size()<b.size();
    });
 cout<<endl<<"Sorted string"<<endl;
  for(auto s: vec)
  {
      cout<<s<<" ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```